# Solving an inequality.

Tags: inequality

I'm looking for a way to solve this inequality. The answer seems quite simple yet I'm so far away!

$$x^2 - 4 + \frac {3}{x}\ < 0$$

Any input would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$x^3-4x+3$ has an integer root ($1$), so it can be factored as
$$x^3-4x+3=(x-1)(x^2+x-3)$$
The quadratic factor has roots equal to $\;\dfrac{-1\pm\sqrt{13}}2$, and the order of the roots (taking into account the pole $x=0$) is $\;\dfrac{-1-\sqrt{13}}2,\,0,\,1,\,\dfrac{-1+\sqrt{13}}2$. It's now easy to conclude.

Comment: Thank you very much! I completely forgot about the quadratic formula for a second, shame on me!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

The inequality is equivalent to the following:

$$f(x) = \dfrac{(x-1)(x^2+x-3)}{x} < 0$$

Now you can factorize $x^2 + x-3$ as well and consider where $f(x)$ changes its sign.

Comment: (+1)  Is it always the same temperamental person who struck?

Comment: @Bernard I downvoted this answer since its original version was not correct.

Comment: @Ramil Please edit it again such that I can cancel my downvote.

Comment: @Yikai Yes, in the original version $f(x)$ was written down incorrectly. Thanks. I added a minor change to the comment.

Answer (score 1):

The inequality can be written as $$\frac{x^3 - 4x + 3}{x} < 0$$ which can further be factorized to $$\frac{(x-1)(x^2 + x - 3)}{x} < 0$$ and then to $$\frac{(x-1)(x-
 \frac{\sqrt 13 - 1}{2})(x - \frac{- \sqrt 13 - 1}{2})}{x} < 0$$
Now it can be found using method of intervals that $$x \in (\frac{- \sqrt 13 - 1}{2}, 0) \cup (0, \frac{\sqrt 13 - 1}{2})$$ which is the required solution to the inequality.